# Run parallel simulations in remote unix cluster from matlab

Tags: matlab, unix, cluster-computing, simulation, gnu-parallel

I want to run simulations in parallel in a remote Cluster calling them from matlab.

I manage to run them in my local Ubuntu machine using.

```
unix('parallel -j4 flow > /dev/null :::: Pool.txt');
```

But when I want it to run it in a remote cluster I really did not mange to make the parallel command to work.

The first problem was to avoid entering the password.

For that I used the sshpass as this

```
unix('sshpass -p password ssh user@cluster.example.com')
```

That get me in to the server but it does not continue to the next command line.

I try so many commands that I do not want to reference here.

But basically can some one that understands well the parallel GNU command usage tell me how can I connect to a cluster. and run the simulations there.  is it better just to make a script at the server and run it from matlab?

Any expert advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with **GNU Parallel** but with configuring `ssh`. First, you must get `ssh` set up, then the rest is easy.

So, on your local Ubuntu machine, you need to create your keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

That will make some files in `$HOME/.ssh`. You now need to copy the public part of those keys to each and every node of the remote cluster where you want to run your parallel jobs:

```
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub CLUSTERUSERNAME@NODE-0
...
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub CLUSTERUSERNAME@NODE-15
```

e.g.

```
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub fred@192.168.0.100
```

Now, test you can `ssh` into each node:

```
ssh fred@node2
```

Then, on your local Ubuntu box, set up your config file for `ssh`, so it will be `$HOME/.ssh/config`

```
Host node0
Hostname 192.168.0.100
User fred

...
...

Host node15
Hostname 192.168.0.115
User fred
```

Now you can just use:

```
ssh node0
```

and it will know that means `fred@192.168.0.100`

Now **GNU Parallel** will work with:

```
parallel -S node0,node1,node2
```

Comment: Hi
I created the key but when I type 
'ssh-copy-id CLUSTERUSERNAME@NODE-0'
I get : /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR:failed to open ID file 'home/USER/.pub': no such file